Exsistitne in lingua Latina verbum pro die post cras?
Ut didici cum rogavi meum praeviosum rogatum in hac agora, lingua Latina habet verbum pro die ante heri: nudiustertius. Sed nescio, habetne ea etiam verbum pro die post cras? Lingua Croatica habet id verbum, id est "preksutra", et lingua Germanica etiam habet, id est "übermorgen". Utra verba leguntur ut "trans-cras".
SUMMARY: Did Latin have a word for the day after tomorrow? Because it did have a word for the day before yesterday: nudiustertius.

Mea quidem sententia melius esset rogatum tuum anglice scribere (vel saltem summittere). Nonnulla enim superscriptorum mihi videntur dubiosae Latinitatis, e.g. "verbum pro," "previosam quaestionem," "habetne verbo," "utra," etc.

@brianpck maybe we should have a rule that questions cannot be submitted tantum Latine. Even though I enjoy the opportunity to read/write Latin discourse, it's less useful for most SE users. I don't know how/where to start that discussion, though.

@Kingshorsey We actually have a Meta question about this. The top-voted answer does say, though, that the question should be summarized in English at the end.

If anyone thinks we should have a clear policy or get an update on the community opinion, feel free to start a new meta discussion.

“On the day after tomorrow” = perendie

scies igitur fortasse cras, summum perendie, Cic. Att. 12, 44, 3; id.
Fam. 16, 17, 3.

Perendination is a regular procedure in Roman law.
